# how to visualize (in .jpg form) the training or test performance of yolov6?

Tags: localhost, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I tried tensor board but I can't access the local host through  google colab

the output of the results are in events.out.tfevents.1686769862.95b239a8a19c.244.1 form how to turn it into graphs in (.jpg form). and if there is another way other than tensor board to visualize these results (training or testing)